# Find two elements which appear in two arrays and put them into another array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("firstName");
var y = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
var z = x && y; // this casuses all of x and all of y to be put into z.
```

How can I find only the elements that have the class name "firstName" and are "td"?

Comment: You can't use logical "AND" to join two nodeLists (the second one should be `getElementsByTagName`)

Comment: `var z = document.querySelectorAll('td.firstName')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll` for that, it returns an array-like nodelist

```
var z = document.querySelectorAll('td.firstName')
```